# Tracing system calls using dtrace

Tags: macos, dtrace

I am running an application that runs with a process Id `423`.
Basically want to debug this process.

The problem is that,
using the command `sudo dtruss -a -t open_nocancel -p 423` I dont see print messages executed and also systems signals like `sudo kill -30 423` dont seem to show in the stack trace. Am I missing something?. How do I achieve this?.

Sample Stack trace below

```
    PID/THRD  RELATIVE  ELAPSD    CPU SYSCALL(args)          = return
  423/0xcf5:  109498638      14      9 open_nocancel("/Users/krishna/.rstudio-desktop/sdb/s-3F25A09C/373AE888\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)    = 21 0
  423/0xcf5:  109509540      20     16 open_nocancel("/Users/krishna/.rstudio-desktop/history_database\0", 0x209, 0x1B6)     = 20 0
  423/0xcf5:  109510342      56     44 open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)        = 20 0
  423/0xcf5:  109516113      19     15 open_nocancel("/Users/krishna/.rstudio-desktop/history_database\0", 0x209, 0x1B6)     = 20 0
  423/0xcf5:  109517099      35     30 open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)        = 20 0
  423/0xcf5:  109576820      16     11 open_nocancel("/Users/krishna/.rstudio-desktop/sdb/s-3F25A09C/373AE888\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)    = 21 0
  423/0xcf5:  109673038      16     10 open_nocancel("/Users/krishna/.rstudio-desktop/sdb/s-3F25A09C/373AE888\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)    = 21 0
```

Comment: This may help [Mac OS X Debugging Magic with DTrace Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECDTRACE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `sudo dtruss -a -t open_nocancel -p 423` will trace *only* the `open_nocancel` system call.  Per the [OS X man page for `dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html):

```
NAME
       dtruss - process syscall details. Uses DTrace.

SYNOPSIS
       dtruss [-acdeflhoLs] [-t syscall] { -p PID | -n name | command }

...

       -t syscall
              examine this syscall only
```

If you want to trace other system calls, you need to either change the `-t ...` argument, or remove it.